# how to use linq for showing image in webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 tables, first one is products and second one productImages
there is one to many relation between products and productImages table. i mean for each productID i have several images. now in the web grid of my index view i would like to show first image in the webgrid. but i do not know how i have to use linq in the webgrid for image column.
i tried this but does not work.

```
 grid.Column("", "Image", @<text><img src="@(Url.Content(Constants.ProductImagePath) + item.ProductImages.First().FileName)" width="100" /></text>)
```

below is my webgrid:

```
 @model IEnumerable<WebStore.Models.Product>



@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 5,ajaxUpdateContainerId:"divGrid");

}

@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "gridStyle", headerStyle: "gridHeader", rowStyle:   "gridRow", alternatingRowStyle: null,htmlAttributes:new{Id="divGrid"},
  columns: new WebGridColumn[] {
grid.Column("ProductName", "Product Name"),
grid.Column("Price", "Price"),
grid.Column("Description", "Description"),
grid.Column("CategoryName","Category Name",x=>x.Category.CategoryName),
grid.Column("", "Image", @<text><img   src="@(Url.Content(Constants.ProductImagePath) +     item.ProductImages.First().FileName)" width="100" /></text>),



grid.Column("","",x=>Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new{id=x.Id})),
grid.Column("","",x=>Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new{id=x.Id})),
grid.Column("","",x=>Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new{id=x.Id}))
```

}
                        )

product class:

```
  public Product()
    {
        this.OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
        this.ProductImages = new HashSet<ProductImage>();
        this.BasketItems = new HashSet<BasketItem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }
}
```

}

product image class:

```
   public partial class ProductImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: item.ProductImages.First().FileName does it retrn you data if you print it ?

Comment: what if it is null ?? I mean no images for one of the product . Also please share .cs code as well .

Comment: Also what is item in this line it should be x ?grid.Column("", "Image", @<text><img   src="@(Url.Content(Constants.ProductImagePath) +     item.ProductImages.First().FileName)" width="100" /></text>),

Comment: i ge error System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<WebStore.Models.ProductImage>' does not contain a definition for 'First'

Comment: when image there is in products table this code works grid.Column("", "Image", @<text><img src="~/Images/@item["Img"]" width="100" /></text>) but now images there are in another table , i would like to use linq for getting first image but i do not know how in this case

Comment: i used  grid.Column("", "Image", x=>@<text><img src="@(Url.Content(Constants.ProductImagePath) + x.ProductImages.First().FileName )" width="100" /></text>) but i got error  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Please don't keep repeating questions.

Comment: my problem fixed https://forums.asp.net/t/2115995.aspx?can+not+use+navagation+properties+in+web+grid